# How to send (model object as) reponse in xml format in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm very new to Ruby and Ruby on Rails and I have been searching for a way to send response in xml format via REST API that I am building using ruby on rails. No luck so far!

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json do
    render json: { terminals: @terminals }
  end
  format.xml do
    render xml: { terminals: @terminals }.to_xml
  end
end
```

It kind of works but the output is something I cannot make sense of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
    <terminals type="Terminal">#&lt;Terminal:0x007f1db02b6900&gt;</terminals>
</hash>
```

I don't even know how to search for this issue online. I've tried going through the documentation be I've found no solution. Really need some help with this one! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is returning the memory address of an object. Perhaps do it without to_xml.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `to_xml`on the object that you want to render. If you use the :xml option, render will automatically call to_xml for you.

```
   respond_to do |format|
      format.xml {render :xml => @terminals}
   end
```

or in Rails 4 simply:

```
render :xml => @terminals
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to